# Will an original Smart Cover work on an iPad 3?

Tags: ipad, smart-cover

I bought an iPad 2 and Apple smart cover last year, before they updated them and got rid of the orange color. Now I'm thinking of upgrading to the new iPad, will my Smart cover work on the new iPad or do I have to shell out another $40 for a new one?

(The reason I ask is because I think the dimensions of the new iPad are slightly different? and the sides are apparently more curved?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [the Smart Cover page on the Apple store:](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD310LL/A?fnode=MTc0MjU2Mjc)

> The iPad Smart Cover is compatible with iPad 2 or later.

Also at [the bottom of the page:](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD310LL/A?fnode=MTc0MjU2Mjc#overview)

[image: This accessory is compatible with the iPad 2 and iPad 3]

So, the answer, based what Apple has said, is yes, the original Smart Cover will fit both the iPad 2 and the iPad 3.

There are also [several](http://store.apple.com/us/question/answers/product/MD310LL/A?fnode=MTc0MjU2Mjc&pqid=QPPY9UJJ2J99JPYHJJ4JJFCPATDU949TTKTTJHFAK27FT97KP) [questions](http://store.apple.com/us/question/answers/product/MD303LL/A?fnode=MTc0MjU2Mjc&pqid=QPU2UX7JKHPJDX9JK2PKCXFX7UXAAT9Y9KTTJHFAK27FT97KP) linked in the product page that say that the cover will fit.

**Edit 9/1/12:**
I did mean to update this when I found the link, but I lost it for a time and recently found it again.

According to [a MacRumors report on March 22nd](http://www.macrumors.com/2012/03/22/some-smart-covers-not-working-properly-on-new-ipad/), some people did (and presumably still are) have some trouble with the magnets on the iPad 3. According to [Marc Booth](http://markshangout.com/blog/2012/3/17/ipad-3-smart-cover-sleepwake-feature-not-working.html), Apple changed the polarity of the magnets sometime in 2011, because "some iPad 2 customers were having issues with their iPads entering sleep mode when they flipped Apple's Smart Cover around flat behind their iPad 2". Marc also reports that "Apple is replacing older Apple Smart Covers at Apple Stores for customers who ask."

Comment: That page though is not about the original one, the one I have is blue on the outside and grey on the inside.

Comment: @daviesgeek You won! :)

Comment: @gentmatt :-) I did.

Comment: @Jonathan Updated my answer for you. Although the Smart Cover was slightly redesigned, the iPad 2 & 3 are the same size, so the Smart Cover will fit both.

Answer (score 3):

## [Yes.](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD306)

> The iPad Smart Cover is compatible with iPad 2 or later.

Answer (score 1):

That it will. There is no change to the smart cover range.

(See [here](http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MD306ZM/A):- the product number is the same as the one I have, and it says compatible with both.

Comment: They removed the orange version and made the inside of the cover the same colour as the outside. I don't have one of those, but the one of the ones that came out at the same time as the iPad 2.

Comment: Apple gave me one of those as a free replacement for my original, which was as you said - there was absolutely no physical shape difference that I could detect when I swapped them over, so you should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

It could depend on magnet polarity.

> Reports on the Apple support forums say that the company will exchange
>   defective covers for new ones at the Apple store, and third-party
>   manufacturers including Targus and Maroo are also offering
>   replacements.

http://www.theverge.com/2012/3/22/2893087/new-ipad-smart-cover-incompatibility-magnet-polarity